# Debian 10 - Ansible 2.10 AWX 17.0.1 Installation without Openshift or Kubernetes

Tags: docker, ansible, debian, ansible-awx

I'm currently trying to install AWX on a debian10 VM.
I followed a lot of tutorial always saying the same thing but I'm not able to have AWX installed.
It seems that the version 17.0.1 only installs on Openshift or Kubernetes clusters.
On my side I only want it running on a local docker (I installed the prerequisites : docker-ce, docker-compose via pip3, ansible 2.10 with community-docker collection, ...)

When launching the installation through : ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml, it skips all the kubernetes steps and finish like this :

```
*TASK [kubernetes : update django super user password] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
TASK [kubernetes : Create the default organization if it is needed.] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
TASK [kubernetes : Delete management pod] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
TASK [kubernetes : Scale up deployment] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=49   rescued=0    ignored=0*
```

I saw in the documentation this thing :

```
Choose a deployment platform

We currently support running AWX as a containerized application using Docker images deployed to either an OpenShift cluster or a Kubernetes cluster. The remainder of this document will walk you through the process of building the images, and deploying them to either platform.

The installer directory contains an inventory file, and a playbook, install.yml. You'll begin by setting variables in the inventory file according to the platform you wish to use, and then you'll start the image build and deployment process by running the playbook.

In the sections below, you'll find deployment details and instructions for each platform:

    OpenShift
    Kubernetes
```

Does it mean we can no more install it on a local docker using ansible ?
Thanks for help

---

[ Edit 25/02 ]
I looked deeper to the issue and found something strange.
I got the code through git clone (git clone https://github.com/ansible/awx.git) and here is my install.yml file content :

```
---
- name: Build and deploy AWX
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - {role: check_vars}
    - {role: kubernetes, when: "openshift_host is defined or kubernetes_context is defined"}
```

Nothing else related to local_docker

But when I look directly to the source code for this last version on github, here is what I see for install.yml :

```
---
- name: Build and deploy AWX
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - {role: check_vars}
    - {role: image_build, when: "dockerhub_base is not defined"}
    - {role: image_push, when: "docker_registry is defined and dockerhub_base is not defined"}
    - {role: kubernetes, when: "openshift_host is defined or kubernetes_context is defined"}
    - {role: local_docker, when: "openshift_host is not defined and kubernetes_context is not defined"}
```

So I know why awx is not installing but I don't know why my git clone do not retrieve the "good" code.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest commits, docker-compose based environment setup documentation has moved into https://github.com/ansible/awx/tree/devel/tools/docker-compose

Or check out the releases page. https://github.com/ansible/awx/releases
Release 17.0.1 still containers local_docker deployment.